# Installing Tensorflow from source

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to install Tensorflow and get it working over the past few days. Whilst I have managed to install TF and get it working as tested by opening Python in the terminal and typing, 
`import tensorflow as tf` 
I have not been successful attempting to retrain Inception v3. I managed to install it from source once by following the instructions laid out [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) however I am no longer able to do so. When I get to the section 'Create the pip package and install' and go to run `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` in the root of my Tensorflow directiory I get the following error.

```
kieran@kieranUbuntu:~/tensorflow$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
ERROR: /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1068:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/spec.json': target 'gen/spec.json' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1068:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/head': target 'gen/head' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1068:1: no such target '//tensorflow/tools/git:gen/branch_ref': target 'gen/branch_ref' not declared in package 'tensorflow/tools/git' defined by /home/kieran/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 3.063s
```

This is the same error I ran into when I managed to install it and then attempted retaining the classifier following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) tutorial. At the section, `bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain`.
I just can't figure out what is going wrong and I have been trying for so long.

I'm using this pip version, # Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied in the incorrect use of ./configure. Whilst it  was ran I currently have two versions of python on my computer, both of which are stored in different locations, when  running ./configure I pointed it to the wrong python version. After rectifying the issue everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should search before ask, [This link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4279) can probably solve your issue.

Comment: Rather presumptuous to assume i did not search. I  did and I was unable to find the issue  until late last night. ./configure was  ran just incorrectly.